# multi row tables

Tags: tables

I'm trying to make a table that has column headings with the units underneath the heading. I using the `\multirow` command, below is a section of the code (I can't add the image of the table output as I am a new user and have no rating to include an image). My problem is the first column heading is distorted. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or able to suggest a better way of doing this?

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Crystallisation optimisation 96 well screen} % title of Table
\centering % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c} % centered columns (4 columns)%
\hline\hline
\multirow{1}Well & [Protein] & pH & [MgCl$_{2}$] & Precipitant& \\
 & (mg.mL$^{-1}$)& & (M)& \\
\hline % inserts single horizontal line
A1 & 7 & 7 & 0.1 & 25\% PEG400\\
A2 & 7 & 7 & 0.1 & 30\% PEG400\\
A3 & 7 & 7 & 0.1 & 35\% PEG400\\
A4 & 7 & 7 & 0.1 & 40\% PEG400\\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Please read the multirow documentation! The syntax you are looking for is: `\multirow{2}{*}{Well}` (notice the brackets). However, I would simply advise to do it without multirow: have one head row with names/variables and one with units (or no unit for dimensionless numbers).

Comment: Try \multirow{2}*{Well}.

Comment: On the side: I would advise to checkout the packages `mhchem` and `siunitx` for easy chemical formulae and correct spacing between numbers and units (percentages for instance).

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you are looking for is: `\multirow{2}{*}{Well}` (notice the brackets). However, I would advise to go without `multirow`: use one head row with names/variables and one with units (or no unit for dimensionless numbers, like the columns for pH and precipitant in your example).

I also took the liberty to use [booktabs](http://texdoc.net/pkg/booktabs)-styled rules as horizontal lines in my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{Crystallisation optimisation 96 well screen} % title of Table
\centering % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c} 
\toprule 
\multirow{2}{*}{Well} & [Protein] & pH & [MgCl$_{2}$] & Precipitant \\
 & (mg.mL$^{-1}$)& & (M) & \\
\midrule
A1 & 7 & 7 & 0.1 & 25\% PEG400\\
A2 & 7 & 7 & 0.1 & 30\% PEG400\\
A3 & 7 & 7 & 0.1 & 35\% PEG400\\
A4 & 7 & 7 & 0.1 & 40\% PEG400\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```